# How to read list which contains comma from CSV file as a column?

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to read CSV file which contains following data :

**Input.csv-**

```
 10,[40000,1][50000,5][60000,14]
 20,[40000,5][50000,2][60000,1][70000,1][80000,1][90000,1]
 30,[60000,4]
 40,[40000,5][50000,14]
```

I want to parse this CSV file and parse it row by row. But these lists contains commas `','` so I'm not getting correct result.

**Program-Code-**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True)
        next(reader,None)
        for read in reader:
            no = read[0]
            splitted_record = read[1]          
            print splitted_record
```

**Output-**

```
[40000
[40000
[60000
[40000
```

I can understand `read.csv` method reads till commas for each column. But how I can read whole lists as a one column?

**Expected Output-**

```
[40000,1][50000,5][60000,14]
[40000,5][50000,2][60000,1][70000,1][80000,1][90000,1]
[60000,4]
[40000,5][50000,14]
```

**Writing stuff to other file-**

```
name_list = ['no','splitted_record']
file_name = 'temp/'+ no +'.csv'
if not os.path.exists(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, 'a')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,delimiter=',',fieldnames=name_list)
    writer.writeheader()
else:
    f = open(file_name, 'a')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,delimiter=',',fieldnames=name_list)
writer.writerow({'no':no,'splitted_record':splitted_record})
```

How I can write this `splitted_record` without quote `""`?

Comment: Why not `open` and *read* without `csv`

Comment: @Moses Koledoye- This is the csv file which has headers also no,splitted_record so I'm reading with **csv.reader**.

Comment: Read line by line and split with a regular expression

Answer (score 1):

you can join those items together, since you know it split by comma

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True)
        next(reader,None)
        for read in reader:
            no = read[0]
            splitted_record = ','.join(read[1:])          
            print splitted_record
```

output

```
[40000,1][50000,5][60000,14]
[40000,5][50000,2][60000,1][70000,1][80000,1][90000,1]
[60000,4]
[40000,5][50000,14]
```

---update---
data is the above output

```
with open(filepath,'wb') as f:
     w = csv.writer(f)
     for line in data:
         w.writerow([line])
```

Comment: @galaxyan- Working file but while writing this record into another file double cotes ("") are encountered. can I remove that also while writing?

Comment: @kit after join, the data become string, so when you write to file, it will have "" on it. I wonder do you want to change the string to list of list.

Comment: @galaxyan- I don't want to change string to list of list, I just want to keep my output file as it is like [40000,1][50000,5][60000,14] without quote instead of **"[40000,1][50000,5][60000,14]"** with quote (").

Comment: @galaxyan not 'cote' but 'quote'

Comment: @galaxyan how are you writing that shows quotes in output file?

Comment: @kit you can use csv write it back. it takes care of quota

Comment: @galaxyan- see my edit. Don't want write as a new list. I just want to keep my data in output file as Expected Output.

Comment: @kit have you tried? it not change type of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own dialect and register it to read as you need.
[https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html](http://dialect)